# Setup proxysql read-write split with both galera cluster and master slave replication

Tags: galera, master-slave-replication, proxysql

I have the following setup:
[image: Galera cluster and master-slave replication setup]

1. Three node galera cluster (galera-1, galera-2, galera-3)
2. galera-2 is master to slave-1 (master-slave replication)
3. slave-1 is master to both slave-2 and slave-3
4. slave-1, slave-2 and slave-3 have `read_only = 1`

I have the following ProxySQL configuration:

```
mysql_servers = (
    {   address = "galera-1"   port = 3306   hostgroup = 2   },
    {   address = "galera-2"   port = 3306   hostgroup = 2   },
    {   address = "galera-3"   port = 3306   hostgroup = 2   },
    {   address = "galera-2"   port = 3306   hostgroup = 5
        max_replication_lag = 5   },    
    {   address = "slave-1"    port = 3306   hostgroup = 5
        max_replication_lag = 5   },
    {   address = "slave-2"    port = 3306   hostgroup = 5
        max_replication_lag = 5   },
    {   address = "slave-3"    port = 3306   hostgroup = 5
        max_replication_lag = 5   }
)

mysql_galera_hostgroups = (
    {
        active = 1  
        backup_writer_hostgroup = 4
        max_transactions_behind = 100
        max_writers = 1
        offline_hostgroup = 1
        reader_hostgroup = 3 
        writer_hostgroup = 2
        writer_is_also_reader = 0    
    }
)

mysql_replication_hostgroups = (
    {
        writer_hostgroup = 5
        reader_hostgroup = 6
    }
)
```

With this configuration:

- Available servers for **writing**:

  - hostgroup 2 (I will always be routing to this one)
  - hostgroup 5
- Available servers for **reading**:

  - hostgroup 3
  - hostgroup 4
  - hostgroup 6

How can I route **read** queries to hostgoups 3, 4 or 6 in a round-robin fashion?

```
mysql_query_rules = 
(
    {
        rule_id = 100
        active = 1
        match_pattern = "^SELECT .* FOR UPDATE"
        destination_hostgroup = 2
        apply = 1
    },
    {
        rule_id = 200
        active = 1
        match_pattern = "^SELECT .*"
        destination_hostgroup = 6
        apply = 1
    },
    {
        rule_id = 300
        active = 1
        match_pattern = ".*"
        destination_hostgroup = 2
        apply = 1
    }
)
```

I've tried mixing groups between Galera and MySQL replication but things get mixed up quite badly.

Is there a way to create a hostgroup of hostgroups so I can route to the "group of groups"?

Comment: If I change the `mysql_replication_hostgroups.reader_hostgroup` to 3 (the same as `mysql_galera_hostgroups.reader_hostgroup`), the Galera monitor will move them to `mysql_galera_hostgroups.offline_hostgroup`. The idea was to have both Galera readers and replication readers in the same hostgroup.

Comment: I read about having more than one ProxySQL, would this be a solution?  ProxySQL 1 to balance between ProxySQL 2 and 3. ProxySQL 2 with a read/write split with the Galera Nodes and PorxySQL 3 with a read/write split between the master (galera-2) and the replicas. Is this an overkill?

Answer (score 0):

Investigating a bit, I have found a possible solution, but I find it a bit an overkill. Installing 3 ProxySQL servers in order to read/write split between Galera and master/slave replicas.

[image]

1. Configure ProxySQL 1 to balance between ProxySQL 2 and 3.
2. ProxySQL 2 configured with a read/write split between Galera nodes
3. ProxySQL 3 configured with a read/write split between master and replicas

Any comments?
It would be great to be able to achieve this with just one ProxySQL server.